# How to plot bars reversed up with negative values?

Tags: matlab, plot, bar-chart, matlab-figure

Starting by this 10x3 `y` matrix, where all its entries are negative values:

```
y = [-56   -58   -60;
     -75   -74   -72;
     -66   -66   -69;
     -67   -69   -71;
     -66   -67   -71;
     -59   -58   -57;
     -69   -71   -69;
     -59   -58   -58;
     -66   -67   -68;
     -75   -73   -72];
```

I need to plot it simply using `bar(y)`, but the bars appear reversed down as shown below:

[image: figure]

How to plot this matrix in the the normal bar direction, while the y-axis ticks not change (i.e., from -95 up to -50 as in the figure) such that the bar which has -50 value is the tallest one and that has -90 is the smallest one?

Comment: I am unsure about your expected output. Is this what you're expecting? https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiOJf.jpg

Comment: yes ,exactly;

How i can do it? @SardarUsama

Comment: which version of MATLAB do you have?

Comment: 2016a  @SardarUsama

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the `bar` plot with an offset of `90` so that you plot positive values instead of negative and then adjust the ticks and tick-labels.

```
bar(y+90);
ax = gca; 
%Limiting # of YTicks to 5 between minimum and maximum. 
%Inputting 5 YtickLabels accordingly. Select them as per your requirement.
ax.YTick = linspace(min(ax.YTick),max(ax.YTick),5);
ax.YTickLabel = strsplit(num2str(-90:10:-50));
```

For R2014a and earlier versions, use `get` and `set` instead of dot notation to manipulate those properties.

***Output:***

[image: out]